# How can I send message with button in bale-messenger by python?

Tags: button, bale-messenger

I couldn't find solution that send message with keyboard button in bale messenger by python!
If you can help, Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you can send a template message instead of keyboard button.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using [python-bale-bot](https://github.com/python-bale-bot/python-bale-bot), it should be something like this.**

```py
import bale
from bale import EventType

bot = bale.Bot("Your Token")

@bot.listen(EventType.READY)
async def on_ready():
     print("READY!")

@bot.listen(EventType.MESSAGE)
async def on_message(message):
     await message.reply("Hey! this is test!", components = bale.Components(
        keyboards=[[bale.Keyboard("Test")]]
     ))

bot.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no keyboard button now. Maybe in future :)